Converting Hijri date to Gregorian Date and calculate elapsed time in Google Sheets
I am working on  some medium datasets in Google Sheets that have columns containing Hijri dates(Arabic Year). I want to change them to Gregorian dates or else count the elapsed time on real time basis. Senior members are requested to kindly help in solving this problem
I  tried to searched for Add-ons from Extensions tab of Google Sheets but could not find anything that  might help.

Convert Hijri Dates to Gregorian

Add ImportJSON file to your spreadsheet's apps script project.

Make sure your Hijri dates are formatted as dd-mm-yyyy

Convert a single date using:
=ImportJSON("http://api.aladhan.com/v1/hToG?date=dd-mm-yyyy","data/gregorian/date","noHeaders") 


Convert an array of dates using:
# Hijri dates in A2:A1000

=LET(rng,A2:A1000,
   api,"http://api.aladhan.com/v1/hToG?date=",
   options,{"data/gregorian/date","noHeaders"},
   IF(rng<>"", ImportJSON(api&rng,options),)) 



If the Hijri dates are not dd-mm-yyyy formatted, you can add a reformat step into the formula above.
Depending on your requirements, you could also write an apps script to perform the conversion, with or without replacement of the original values, using the same API endpoint.
